# PyCharm auto suggestion doesn't appear

Tags: python, pycharm

No Suggestion Appears:

[image]

My Setting:

[image]

Suddenly PyCharm auto suggestion doesn't appear.

For instance, to make a class, when I type just 'init', PyCharm used to suggest `__init__(self)`.

I am begginer of Python and have little knowledge about pycharm interpreter.

Is this problem happening because of interpreter?

Comment: First place I would look is `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Code Completion`

Comment: you can also download [kite](https://www.kite.com/) package which helps in auto code completion

Answer (score 0):

Had the same in Visual studio code. Removed Pylance extention and got it back.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).